# haskell : what is wrong with this piece of code

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compile this piece of code but it doesn't work and I don't get it:

```
division :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
division _ (Maybe 0) = Nothing
division (Maybe a) (Maybe b) = Just (a `div` b)
```

Comment: `Maybe` `Maybe` is not a constructor of `Maybe a`

Comment: i meant that the function take two parameters of type MAybe and return a maybe value. any corrections?

Comment: yes, but in the body of the function, you can not use `(Maybe 0)`, etc. Then you have to pick a constructor, like `Just 0`, not `Maybe 0`.

Comment: As a style thing: I recommend leaving the arguments as bare `Int`s rather than `Maybe Int`s, as in ```division :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int; division _ 0 = Nothing; division a b = a `div` b```. If you need the arguments to be `Maybe`s, then you can use `do` notation; if `ma :: Maybe Int` and `mb :: Maybe Int`, then `do a <- ma; b <- mb; division a b` is well-typed.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're missing a `Just` in `division a b = a \`div\` b`.

Comment: @gallais Thanks, you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Maybe a` is defined as:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

so you **can not put `Maybe a`** in the function defintion, only in the signature:

```
division :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
division _ (Just 0) = Nothing
division (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a `div` b)
```

Furthermore the function is **not total**: not every possible case of input is handled by the function, so this could result in an exception. So you better return something in those cases (usually one returns `Nothing`):

```
division :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
division _ (Just 0) = Nothing
division (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a `div` b)
division _ _ = Nothing
```

Finally we can use `Integral i` as type, instead of `Int` and make the function more generic:

```
division :: Integral i => Maybe i -> Maybe i -> Maybe i
division _ (Just 0) = Nothing
division (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a `div` b)
division _ _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Daniel Wagner's comment and Willem Van Onsem's point about `Integral`, this is how I would write the function:

```
division :: Integral a => a -> a -> Maybe a
division _ 0 = Nothing
division p q = Just (div p q)
```

To use it with `Maybe` arguments, you can simply write

```
division <$> m <*> n
```

or, equivalently,

```
liftA2 division m n
```

where `liftA2` is in `Control.Applicative`.